# why aren't cshtml files rendering iis7.5 windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net, razor, iis-7.5, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

since i've already wasted 5 days on this problem with .cshtml asp.net web pages i figured why not ask the gurus.

HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   xxxxxxxxx:80/bakery/default.cshtml
Physical Path   xxxxxxxx\bakery\default.cshtml
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions>
                <remove fileExtension=".cshtml" />
                <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
   </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" />     
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script, Write, Execute">
    <clear />
    <remove name="cshtml-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="cshtm-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />        
    <add name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.cshtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.cshtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />        
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

for the record:
yes .NET 4.0 is installed that is an obvious requirement
yest the app pool for this app is set to "allow 32 bit applictions" and the app pool is set to run in integrated mode.
server: windows server 2008 r2
and as you can see from above runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is set to true. so please don't ask me these silly questions that anyone who
that has done any troubleshooting would already have done.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, i am using a virtual host server, and I solved this with copying all MVC3 and Razor dlls into the bin folder.

1. If you create your web in "application":
   right click your web project, choose "add deployable dependencies", and rebuild again, then try to deploy it.
2. If you create the "Web Site", not application:
   Copy these manually into your bin folder:

   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
   System.Web.Helpers.dll
   System.Web.Mvc.dll
   System.Web.Razor.dll
   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
   System.Web.WebPages.dll
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

Comment: hi Edi - thanks for your reply. yea i tried the bin deployment method for a "web site" and copied all the necessary binaries as you mentioned. result -- nothing. nada. zilch. Now, the funny thing is that when i launch the site via web matrix 2 using the built in IIS 8 express everything works fine. i just don't get it. IIS express uses a local port on local host i.e. http://localhost:9887/{path to the path}.cshtml -- again when using localhost via webmatrix everything is fine. unfortunately, users can't browse to "localhost" but will need to navigate to the domain name and path to cshtml file.

Comment: do you have <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/> in your web.config/appsettings?

Comment: yes i have that app key added. still no luck. i get the error: Failed to Execute URL.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Failed to Execute URL.

Comment: seems IIS need a patch http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5272 and also try to do IIS ROOT → request Filtering → Filename Extensions Tab → Edit Feature Settings → check Allow unlisted file name extensions

Comment: Edi -  the path was already on the system. I do go ahead and reinstall IIS and I'm still getting errors with executing .cshtml files. Basically I just added a MIME file type

Comment: The MIME file type is ".cshtml=text/HTML" and I included the aapnet_isapi.dll entries as mentioned above. So a request for .cshtml files renders the actual razor source code instead if the rendered HTML. Why is this happenning?

Comment: You don't need to add cshtml to MIME, in my iis, i didn't have this MIME type but MVC site still working fine. Have you install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211 ? this is required. After installtion, you can find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages and then your IIS will serve cshtml files.

Comment: Edi, MVC is already on the server. Anyway, here is the error message---- Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. Compiler Error Message: CS0115: 'ASP._Page_nothing_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override Source Error: Line 40: } Line 41: Line 42: public override void Execute() { Line 43: Line 44:

Comment: I am getting the above error after adding the following key to the appsettings section -- <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />